# Gitlab multi pipeline override variable passed to new pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I am testing the new multi project functionality for Gitlab where I can trigger the next pipeline from my current pipeline:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html

I only have one problem. I have two pipelines A and B. in both pipelines I define global variables in the yaml file.

Pipeline A:

```
variables:
    Name: 'vw-$CI_PIPELINE_ID'
stages:
    - hello
    - trigger
hello:
    stage: hello
    script:
        - Write-Host "Hello World"
trigger:
    stage: trigger
    trigger: 
        project: my/PipelineB
        branch: master
```

Pipeline B

```
variables:
    Name: 'vw-$CI_PIPELINE_ID'
stages: 
    - triggered
triggered:
    stage: triggered
    script: 
        - write-host $Env:Name
```

Expectation is that the variables would be overwritten in Pipeline B.

Actual outcome is the variable has the same value as defined in Pipeline A

Comment: @Explicitsour from the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#with-the-variables-keyword)  "Upstream pipelines take precedence over downstream ones. If there are two variables with the same name defined in both upstream and downstream projects, the ones defined in the upstream project take precedence"

Comment: Did you find a solution, @Explicitsoul ? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want your global variables (in your case "Name") to be passed to the downstream pipeline, just disable inheritance as described here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#prevent-global-variables-from-being-passed

in your case Pipeline A would look like this:

```
variables:
    Name: 'vw-$CI_PIPELINE_ID'
stages:
    - hello
    - trigger
hello:
    stage: hello
    script:
        - Write-Host "Hello World"
trigger:
    stage: trigger
    trigger: 
        project: my/PipelineB
        branch: master
    inherit:
        variables: false
```